# Why i am getting only the last output in csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a bunch of urls in a csv file and I have to extract data from those urls into another csv file. I extracted the data from those urls into a dataframe using my code below, but when it comes to save those extracted data into output csv, it only shows me the last extracted data (i.e  if I have 10 urls in demo.csv, only the extracted data of 10th url is seen in the output csv, not all the urls' data).

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

with open('demo.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        url = row[0]
        header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36/8mqHiSuL-56"}
        response = requests.get(url, headers= header)
        print(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        website= soup.find('div', class_="arrange__373c0__UHqhV gutter-2__373c0__3Zpeq vertical-align-middle__373c0__2TQsQ border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT")
        if website is None:
            website = '-'
        else:
            website = website.text.replace('Business website','')
            print(website)
        time.sleep(2)

    dict = {'url': [url], 'website': [website]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    df.to_csv('export_dataframe.csv', index= False)
```

Comment: i don't want to overwrite i simply want to save extracted data into a new csv file "export_dataframe.csv"

Comment: Yes i am getting the last url data and i want all the urls data save into csv file

Comment: i did as you said df.to_csv('export_dataframe.csv', mode='a', index=False) but nothing changed still getting the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the identation of the line where you are adding your data into a dict. It is outside the loop, therefore only adds the last url data. I have pointed it out by comment in the code below.

```
import csv
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []
with open('demo.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        url = row[0]
        header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36/8mqHiSuL-56"}
        response = requests.get(url, headers= header)
        print(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        website= soup.find('div', class_="arrange__373c0__UHqhV gutter-2__373c0__3Zpeq vertical-align-middle__373c0__2TQsQ border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT")
        if website is None:
            website = '-'
        else:
            website = website.text.replace('Business website','')
            print(website)
        time.sleep(2)

        data.append([url, website])   # this line is out of loop in your code, also I am using list here just to simplify (you can use dict still)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['url','website'])
    df.to_csv('export_dataframe.csv', index= False)
```